# How to make two similar functions into one function?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two functions that do the basically same thing on two different classes.... each class has different properties.

For example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int ColorID {get;set;}
    public string ColorDescription {get;set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int TypeID {get;set;}
    public string TypeDescription {get;set;}
}

public void ExFunctionSaveA(ClassA aClass)    
{
  aClass.ColorID=1;
  aClass.ColorDescription="My Color";
  Save();
}

public void ExFunctionSaveB(ClassB bClass)    
{
  bClass.TypeID=2;
  bClass.TypeDescription="My Type";
  Save();
}
```

As you can see the classes and the functions have the same type structure, just the property names are different... but I feel like I am repeating code doing this

Is there a way to make ExFunctionA and ExFunctionB into one function, so that I could use this for all classes that have similar structure

I know I could do some sort of generic thing like

```
public void ExFunctionSave<T>()   // T is either ClassA or ClassB
{
   .
   .
   .
   .
   Save();
}
```

but how would I handle the properties of each

Comment: Outside of interfaces/inheritance which have been suggested already. I would use the constructors in each class to set the ID and description for there respective properties. This then just leaves the method Save(), which you can't remove unless you have a base class or generic base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can alter the definitions of your classes, then the best approach would be to make them implement a common interface that contains the properties you want to access:

```
public interface IDescribable
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ColorID 
    { 
        get { return ID; } 
        set { ID = value; } 
    }

    public string ColorDescription 
    { 
        get { return Description; } 
        set { Description = value; } 
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int TypeID 
    { 
        get { return ID; } 
        set { ID = value; } 
    }

    public string TypeDescription 
    { 
        get { return Description; } 
        set { Description = value; } 
    }
}

public void ExFunctionSave(IDescribable d, int id, string desc)    
{
    d.ID = id;
    d.Description = desc;
    Save();
}
```

Comment: This worked..... I actually was using Linq classes.. so I actually implemented this in each of their partial classes.... works like a charm.... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using a generic, why not use inheritance to solve this?

```
public class theBase
{
    string ID;
    string Description;
}
public class theColor : theBase
{
}

public class theType : theBase
{
}

public void ExFunctionSaveA(theBase base)    
{
    base.ID=1;
    base.Description="My Color";
    Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more you can do unless the the 2 classes implement the same interface which has the function. In your case, even the function signatures are different.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an Interface with attributes id and description.
The clases that has this structure could implement that interface.
And your method receive as parameter the interface and execute the moethods ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Reflection will let your code receive a `ClassA`, and discover that it has a `ColourID` and a `ColorDescription`. Likewise, when you receive a `ClassB`, you can discover its `TypeID` and `TypeDescription`. It's cool.

I would probably recommend a common interface, at least for your example, but if you're trying to something more complex and more generic, Reflection is the way to go.